# I am running a script in SQL Server and get the 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric.'

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run the script below

```
SELECT 
    (ISNULL(AMOUNT, '') + '-' + ISNULL(TRAN_ID, '') + '-' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), TRAN_DATE, 112), '-')) AS TRAN_ID_NEW,
    ID,
    ACCOUNT_STATUS,
    ACCT_BAL, ACCT_BAL_DATE,
    AMOUNT,
    AUTH_IP_ADDRESS,
    BRANCH_ID,
    ENTRY_TIME,
    TRAN_CURRENCY,
    TRAN_DATE,
    TRAN_ID,
    TRAN_PARTICULAR,
    TRAN_SUB_TYPE, TRAN_TYPE,
    VALUE_DATE,
    ACCOUNT,
    REF_DESC,
    ISNULL(REF_DESC, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(TRAN_PARTICULAR, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(AMOUNT, '') AS TRAN_PARTICULAR_NEW
FROM
    Txn;
```

but I get an error:

> 'Error converting data type varchar to numeric'

Please any solution

Comment: What about the error don't you understand? It's telling you the problem, you're trying to insert a `varchar` into a `numeric` column, and that `varchar` can't be implicitly converted to a `numeric`. Looking at your SQL, that first expression would seem a good place to start.

Comment: My guess is that either/both AMOUNT and TRAN_ID are numeric dataypes (int, decimal...). Then you try to add that to a varchar and it will fail. Also, using ISNULL(SomeInt, '') will NOT return an empty string. It will do an implicit conversion of an empty string to an int which will be 0.